# firebaseui.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to add Firebase ui auth on my app using [Google's official documentation on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web).

The email sign in is working fine, but I'm getting issue with the phone sign in option.

On clicking the Sign in with phone and entering the 6 digit code I get on my number, I'm not able to sign up or sign in.

[image]

The round loading circle spins endlessly and doesn't redirect me to the `signInSuccessUrl` defined in my `main.js`.

The error I get in the console is this:

```
firebaseui.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Ca (firebaseui.js:82)
    at Fl (firebaseui.js:323)
    at firebaseui.js:324
    at firebaseui.js:281
    at El.<anonymous> (firebaseui.js:238)
    at oe (firebaseui.js:140)
    at ne (firebaseui.js:139)
    at ni (firebaseui.js:219)
    at li.h (firebaseui.js:219)
    at le (firebaseui.js:136)
Ca @ firebaseui.js:82
Fl @ firebaseui.js:323
(anonymous) @ firebaseui.js:324
(anonymous) @ firebaseui.js:281
(anonymous) @ firebaseui.js:238
oe @ firebaseui.js:140
ne @ firebaseui.js:139
ni @ firebaseui.js:219
li.h @ firebaseui.js:219
le @ firebaseui.js:136
he @ firebaseui.js:137
b @ firebaseui.js:134
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Web flow</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.6.0/firebaseui.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Site Web flow</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div id="loader">Loading...</div>
        <div id="sign-in-status"></div>
        <div id="sign-in"></div>
        <div id="account-details"></div>
        <button id="signOutButton">Signout</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.6.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.js file:

```
let config = {
    apiKey: '##',
    authDomain: '##',
    projectId: '##'
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();
// const auth = firebase.auth();

let uiConfig = {
    signInOptions: [ 
        {
            provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            requireDisplayName: true
        },
        {
            provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            defaultCountry: 'IN'
        }
    ],

    signInSuccessUrl: './success.html',
    tosUrl: '#',
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccess: (currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) => {
            return true;
        },
        signInFailure: (error) => {
            return handleUIError(error);
        },
        uiShown: () => {
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
};


// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
let ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

// The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
ui.disableAutoSignIn();


initApp = function() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            let displayName = user.displayName;
            let email = user.email;
            let emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            let photoURL = user.photoURL;
            let uid = user.uid;
            let phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
            let providerData = user.providerData;
            user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
                document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
                document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
                document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                    displayName: displayName,
                    email: email,
                    emailVerified: emailVerified,
                    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                    photoURL: photoURL,
                    uid: uid,
                    accessToken: accessToken,
                    providerData: providerData
                }, null, '  ');
            });
        } else {
            // User is signed out.
            document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
            document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
            document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    initApp()
});


document.getElementById('signOutButton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        console.log('Signed out');
    })
})
```

I do have enabled the sign in with email and phone in my Firebase console. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you file an issue in the FirebaseUI-web repo to confirm this is not a bug?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in Phone number sign-in flow in FirebaseUI 2.6.0. https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/314. We have a fix and released 2.6.1.  Anyone experiencing the same issue, please update firebaseUI to latest version 2.6.1.

Answer (score 3):

update to latest firebaseui 2.6.1

npm install firebaseui@2.6.1

OR

npm install firebaseui@latest

OR
npm install firebaseui@latest --save